# How do I remove 1 out of 4 light fixtures from a two way switch arrangement?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I have 4 light fixtures on the exterior of the house (pictured blue=lights, green=switches). 2 of them are on a wall along the stairs, 2 are at installed on the ceiling of an overhang in front of the garage.

All 4 of these fixtures are controlled by two light switches, one upstairs in the main level of the house, and one in the garage right inside the door.

I would like to install a Ring Floodlight Cam on the garage light closest to the door, how would I take that one fixture off the circuit so that it always receives power[image]?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved please?

Comment: Does that include switches too or just light fixture boxes? Would I need to do every single fixture to verify?

Comment: You'll need the switches for sure, and at least one light fixture (if not two, or even all four)

Comment: Thank you! I'll do this first thing tomorrow!

Comment: Since there is no hot feed to the location, you'll need to run new cable to the RingCam location.  Are you sure you want it permanently on? I would recommend installing a separate on/off switch for that one fixture.

Comment: That is a great point, if I have to run new wire anyways I might as well also so that one on a switch, maybe just in the garage next to the other one.

Comment: There are different ways  circuit like this could be wired. To power a camera you need both a hot (independent of the light switches) and a neutral. I would first examine the insides of the two switches and see if you have access to unswitched hot and neutral there. I would look at the garage switch box first. You could have a wiring scheme which would give access to a hot and a neutral in each switch box but this is unlikely.

Comment: Most likely access to both an always hot wire and its neutral will be only in one switch box. But if you start rearranging connections and get mixed up,  you could end up with a non functioning circuit.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much need to run a new cable to that outlet and re-wire the existing cable to bypass that outlet.

inspection of the outlets may reveal the possibility for a different option, but I'm not expecting it to.